# google analytics for responsive design

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've started with Google Analytics this year so I'm still learning a lot.

I have stumbled onto this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/28/responsive-web-design-google-analytics/

And I thought it really interesting but I'm struggling. I implemented it for this website: 
http://conversionadvantage.com/

but now my GA stopped tracking; telling me I don't have the code on my website.

Can someone give me pointers please as what I could have done wrong? My code looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); 

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension2': WURFL.complete_device_name,
  'dimension4': WURFL.form_factor,
  'dimension3': WURFL.is_mobile
});
</script>
```

I just have different dimensions since nr 1 is taken. The developer also added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//wurfl.io/wurfl.js"></script>
```

So any thoughts for a newbie?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Wurfl](http://wurfl.io/) is a script for device detection that is used to determine device name etc. So you need to include this before your pageview calls else the variables will not be set (which will result in a javascript error, hence GA will not track anything).

Device Name and "is_mobile" are not necessary since this is already tracked by Google Analytics.